# Openpose gives error:The CPU/GPU pointer data cannot be accessed from a different thread

Tags: openpose

I want to initialize an openose instance,save it as a class field,and this class implemented some grpc related logic,will listen on a port,and I want pass the request(an image) from this port to saved openpose instance for detection,then return back detection result to this port.

After googling.I found PyOpenpose,and implement my design like this:

```
  class PosingServer:
    def __init__(self, setting=PosingSetting):
        self.setting=setting
        self.initNetwork()

    def detect(self, req):
            #detect pose
            net.detectPose(req.image)
            #detect pose
           return net.getKeypoints(net.KeypointType.POSE)[0]

    def initNetwork(self):
        setting = self.setting
        self.net = OP.OpenPose(setting.poseSize, setting.faceHandSize, setting.outSize,\
                               setting.modelType, setting.modelFolder, setting.logLevel,\
                               setting.downloadHeatmaps)

   *****grpc related stuffs*******
```

After PosingServer running,it can receive rpc request and perform detection but this line:

```
return net.getKeypoints(net.KeypointType.POSE)[0]
```

gives error:

```
The CPU/GPU pointer data cannot be accessed from a different thread.

Coming from:
- src/openpose/pose/poseExtractor.cpp:checkThread():341
- src/openpose/pose/poseExtractor.cpp:checkThread():345
- src/openpose/pose/poseExtractor.cpp:getPoseKeypoints():265
ERROR    Exception calling application: 
Error:
The CPU/GPU pointer data cannot be accessed from a different thread.

Coming from:
- src/openpose/pose/poseExtractor.cpp:checkThread():341
- src/openpose/pose/poseExtractor.cpp:checkThread():345
- src/openpose/pose/poseExtractor.cpp:getPoseKeypoints():265
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_server.py", line 377, in _call_behavior
    return behavior(argument, context), True
  File "server/pose/PosingServer.py", line 81, in carryOut
    return self.detector.detect(req)
  File "server/pose/PosingServer.py", line 40, in detect
    return net.getKeypoints(net.KeypointType.POSE)[0])
RuntimeError: 
Error:
The CPU/GPU pointer data cannot be accessed from a different thread.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Just wondering, have you solved it? openpose is very hard to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PoseExtractor` object should be initialize with the function `PoseExtractor::initializationOnThread()` before you can call `getPoseKeypoints()`. I got the exact same same error while developing my own multithreaded application because the initialization was called from the parent thread while I was trying to get the pose keypoints from a child thread. I solved the problem by making sure both functions were called within the same thread.